# Difference between 'appears to be' and 'proves to be' or 'turns out to be'

Tags: meaning, expressions

Is there a difference between 'appears to be' and 'proves to be'? Can I say, when describing the result of a long calculation, that *the result appears/proves to be zero*? I am certain that the result is zero and 'appears' seems to be inappropriate here because it bears the sense of uncertainty, meaning 'looks like', whereas  'proves' just states the fact. I also believe that 'proves to be' is just a more elevated version of 'turns out to be'. But I rarely find 'proves to be' in textbooks or research papers.

Comment: They probably just use "is". Sometimes concise is better and textbooks should alway be as long as they need to be and as short as possible. Conference paper in particular often have a page limit. Otherwise, you are correct, "appears" implies uncertainty.

Comment: I often find 'turns out to be' but almost never find 'proves to be'.

Comment: 'Prove to be' is _very_ close in meaning to 'turn out to be', but is in a much more formal register (and was often used in textbooks etc at one time). [The McGraw-Hill Dictionary of  ... Idioms ...](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/prove+to+be) includes examples which are in a less formal (some might say inappropriately informal) setting: << prove to be something:
be shown to be someone or something; be found to be someone or something. _Jo proved to be a good friend when she lent me some money._ / _The food proved to be spoiled when I smelled it._ >> // 'appears to be': _NO_, as you say.